# Can the Kotlin Compiler Require non-null assertion?

Tags: kotlin, null, nullreferenceexception

Can the Kotlin Compiler require non-null assertions?

for example. I'm getting a query result from JOOQ, and the relting type is `Record!`. But the compiler allows me to access members without checking for null.

```
val orderResult = RowanDatabaseConnector.runInContext(DatabaseContext.BOOKSTORE) {
    it.select(SPREE_ORDERS.asterisk())
        .from(SPREE_ORDERS)
        .where(SPREE_ORDERS.ID.eq(orderId.toInt()))
        .fetchOne()
}

return Cart(
    user = currentUser,
    subTotal = orderResult.get(SPREE_ORDERS.ITEM_TOTAL).toFloat(),
    taxTotal = orderResult.get(SPREE_ORDERS.ADDITIONAL_TAX_TOTAL).toFloat(),
    total = orderResult.get(SPREE_ORDERS.TOTAL).toFloat(),
    lineItems = listOf()
)
```

Is there something similar to Typescript's `strictNullCheck` that would require that I assert that `orderResult` is not null?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For *platform types* (any type ending with `!`), you can use an explicit type specification to declare whether it is supposed to be nullable or not.

If you want to make it explict that `orderResult` might be null, then you could write it like this:

```
val orderResult: Record? = /* trimmed */
```

Conversely, if you want to make it explicit that `orderResult` can't possibly be null, then you could write:

```
val orderResult: Record = /* trimmed *
```

By choosing one of these two options, the type will be `Record?` or `Record` instead of `Record!`. And, as such, you will get the null safety you're used to from Kotlin.